# Internet Explorer 11(Windows-10) not displaying bright-cove video

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, brightcove

I am new to the Angular development. I am trying to include brightcove video (In-Page embed code) in Angular HTML page. And it's working on all windows-10 browsers Chrome, Edge and Firefox except on IE 11.

Video Code:

```
<video data-video-id="5076962725001" data-account="1486906377" data-player="default" data-embed="default" data-application-id class="video-js" controls></video> 
<script src="//players.brightcove.net/1486906377/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
```

source: https://support.brightcove.com/choosing-correct-embed-code#inpage

In IE, I am getting this error [IE 11 error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTYhH.png) and there are no console error messages.

FYI - This video is working fine on Windows-7 IE-11.

Answer (score 0):

The Brightcove Player uses MSE on Windows 8.1+ and IE 11 to play HLS and DASH. For IE11 on Windows < 8.1, it supports Flash for HLS (fall back to MP4 if Flash is disabled) and Silverlight for DASH.

Based on the error that no suitable source was found, it seems like you might not have MP4 renditions or that Flash (HLS) or Silverlight (DASH) is disabled.

If you have any further questions, feel free to reach out to our support team.

reference: https://support.brightcove.com/brightcove-player-system-requirements